# Dynamically generate link_to for different models using common partial - Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

i want to use a common partial to render a listing page and its going good expect i am facing a problem to generate dynamic link_to for :edit and :delete action which is common.

so i have @menu and @picture model in two different views rendering the same common partial (which i created).

this is my common partial.

### shared/_index_common_grid.html.erb

```
               <% pictures.each do |picture| %>
                  <div class="col-sm-4 pull-left">
                      <div class="thumbnail">
                          <div class="caption"> 
                               <h4><%= picture.title.capitalize%></h4>
                              <p class="text-muted">
                              <!--THIS IS WHERE I WANT TO HANDLE DYNAMIC GENERATION OF LINK_TO FOR @picture and @menu models --> 
                                 <%= link_to "Edit", [:edit, current_user,@request,@shop,picture]%>
                              |  <%= link_to "Delete", [current_user,@request,@shop,picture],:data=>{:confirm=>"Are you sure ?"}%>
                              | <span class="pull-right"><%= show_formatted_date(picture.created_at)%></span>                                
                              </p>
                          </div>
                      </div>
                  </div> 
                <%end%>
```

this is my one view using above common partial,there is one more similar to this except i pass different model.

```
##my view page --------pictures/index
                  <%unless @pictures.blank?%>   
                      <%= render partial: "shared/index_common_grid", locals: {pictures: @pictures}%>
                  <%end%>
```

***I dont want to go with switch case in application_helper which can be done easily.***

Comment: So you are using this partial to list the `pictures` and `menus`? Just the issue is link for edit and delete for pictures and menus will be different? What are the required `params` for the menu? And are you on rails 3 or rails 4?

Comment: its Rails 4(mentioned in the question :0).Yeah..i want dynamic links to each resource...

Comment: So what is the link for the `menus`? Means there are options like `url_for` in rails which might help you. But that depends on the parameters required for each of them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use layouts with your partials. See the API docs for more details.

## Rendering pictures with layouts

First, rewrite `pictures/index.html.erb` to:

```
<%= render partial: 'picture', layout: 'shared/index_common_grid', collection: @pictures, as: :object %>
```

Second, rewrite `shared/index_common_grid.html.erb` to:

```
<div class="col-sm-4 pull-left">
  <div class="thumbnail">
    <div class="caption"> 
      <h4><%= object.title.capitalize%></h4>
      <p class="text-muted">
      <%= yield %> | <span class="pull-right"><%= show_formatted_date(object.created_at)%></span>                                
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Thrid, create `pictures/_picture.html.erb`:

```
<%= link_to "Edit", [:edit, current_user, @request, @shop, picture]%>
|  <%= link_to "Delete", [current_user, @request, @shop, picture], :data=>{:confirm=>"Are you sure ?"}%>
```

## Adding other types of objects

If you want to render other types of objects (menus in your example) then:

1. Add `menus/index.html.erb` with a content similar to `pictures/index.html.erb` (replace `picture` and `@pictures` with `menu` and `menus`).
2. Add `menus/_menu.html.erb` with links rendered appropriately for menus.

Comment: Thanks @Greg...this is good approach but i am  looking  furthermore for a way to handle all objects by just one CONCERN method...